# What should happen to the license tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just stumbled upon the [creative-commons](/questions/tagged/creative-commons) tag. It's a conglomeration of of 52 questions which are mostly legal questions and questions which are only loosely related to the license at all.

As Stack Overflow does not deal with legal questions, the tag seems to be off-topic.

Should we plow through these questions and just remove the tag, does a moderator want to burninate it or should we keep it?

There are also related tags:

- [gpl](/questions/tagged/gpl)
- [lgpl](/questions/tagged/lgpl)
- [licensing](/questions/tagged/licensing)
- [freeware](/questions/tagged/freeware)
- [copyleft](/questions/tagged/copyleft)
- [mit-license](/questions/tagged/mit-license)

Comment: <badJoke data-reason="Fix Nijansen's Parser">I keep mine on my car at all times. Otherwise, I get pulled over. </badJoke>

Comment: @AndrewBarber people like you are the reason why my parse comments with xml parser approach kept on crashing XD

Comment: @nijansen There; all fixed!

Comment: @AndrewBarber see, that's much better!